# Disabled certain radio button that containing class

Tags: javascript, disabled-control

I am trying to disable certain radio button that has class using javascript like this :

```
if( $("input[type=radio]").hasClass("class-full") ){
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
}
```

This code is unable to disable the radio button with class `class-full`. What is the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
$("input[type=radio].class-full").attr('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

disable with ID,Class,Name

list radio for name

```
   $("input[name='ticketID']").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('disabled', true);
   });
```

for ID

```
 $("input[id='ticketID1']").attr('disabled', true);
```

see here [demo](https://codepen.io/thamtucity/pen/rpzQBV)